# Boost – Cache expiration does not clear cache in views pages

Tags: 7, caching

When a node is edited and saved the Cache expiration module should clear the cache on that node, which it does. However if that same node is used in a View, I have discovered that the old content still shows. Unfortunately 90% of the main content is shown using Views.

So in the cache expiration configuration page I have ticked the "Custom pages" option and entered `products|wildcard`, because all sub pages after products/ contains views that need to be cleared. But this does not work.

I have tried to use `drush cc views` (success message), which does not work, `drush cc all` does not show the new content either. The only thing that actually works is to go to admin/config/performance and click the `Clear all caches` button.

What is the best way to sort this problem, so that the Cache expiration module also works on Views?

EDITED:

> I haven't found the solution for this problem yet. Any ideas would be
>   really helpful. Anyone?
>   I should probably also mention that I use the Boost module to chache my pages, along with the Cache Expiration module.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution was simple. Apparently you cannot use aliases in the Custom pages settings in the Cache expiration module. By adding `taxonomy/terms|wildcard` in the custom pages box, and also setting the cache to `None` in each concerned View (in the Advanced section), the cache expiration worked as wanted.

Hope this helps, if anyone else has this problem.